# Best way to handle autocorrelation in residuals from panel data regression (FE)

Tags: standard-error, autocorrelation, panel-data

What would be the best way to handle autocorrelated residuals in my panel data analysis (Fixed Effects). What I've tried:

-Adding different regressors (no luck there), and besides the current model is theoretically and intuitively justified.
-Adding AR(1) term on the right hand side, will take away most of the autocorrelation, but I'm not fond of the new model.

I'm working in Eviews but if necessary I could use Matlab or R too.

I read a lot about Autocorrelation robust standard errors, applying this to my residuals would solve the problem right? Possibly making coefficients insignificant, but the current result (with autocorrelations) is not that valid.

So how can I come up with these autocorrelation robust errors, the easiest way (software-wise)?

Comment: Cindy,

I had a similar question recently. See the answer [here][1].

  [1]: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160837/solution-for-autocorrelation-in-linear-regression-model-economic-data