# Correcting autocorrelation with MA in a regression

Tags: time-series, econometrics, autocorrelation, arma, macroeconomics

I would need some advice on a multivariate regression problem. I am running regressions with macroeconomic data at first difference and using a AR(1) as regressor to correct autocorrelation (it makes Eviews do iterative regressions). However some models still contain autocorrelation with this method.

I tried to introduce a moving average MA(1) in the model and the regression didn’t show any more autocorrelation. But am I allowed to use a MA(1) as a regressor ? For example can I estimate X = c + a*Y + MA(1) + AR(1) ?

If not, would you have another method to eliminate autocorrelation?

Comment: Please see a similar question that I had asked here:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160837/solution-for-autocorrelation-in-linear-regression-model-economic-data%20/]

Comment: Thank you for your indication. The difference in my case, is that I also want to use a MA term as a regressor.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to are ARIMA models.They consist of AR, MA and Integrated component(first difference). You can read about them in detail.

You're allowed to use anything as long as you don't use future data in you model.

P.S. If this doesn't answer your question, please guide me about what your query is about.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.

I know a bit about ARIMA models, but it seems to me that it is not my case here. I am trying to explain a series by itself and by an other one. So I use an other variable as a regressor (called Y in the equation above). Can it still be considered as an ARIMA ?

Thanks!

Comment: @BladeVsResiduals, then you are either dealing with a vector autoregression (VAR) or a regression with ARMA errors, see which one fits you case better.

Answer (score 1):

If you have regressions of the form

$$ y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,t} + \dotsc + \beta_K x_{K,t} + \varepsilon_t $$

where the $x$s are exogenous and you are interested in $\beta$s* (which could be thought of as structural parameters), then you may try regression with ARMA errors (see e.g. [here](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/)). This setup preserves the original model (so you obtain $\beta$s immediately) and at the same time fixes the problem of autocorrelated errors. You could implement the model in R by using functions `arima` or `auto.arima` supplying them with exogenous regressors (the $x$s).

It would be something similar (although *not* quite the same) as your idea of including both AR and MA terms directly into the model equation. That would result in an ARMAX model (see the same source), which is a valid model, although its coefficients may be a little difficult to interpret.

If, on the other hand, you have regressions of the form

$$ y_{1,t} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,t} + \dotsc + \beta_K x_{K,t} + \gamma_2 y_{2,t} + \dotsc + \gamma_L y_{L,t} + \varepsilon_t $$

(with or without $x$s) where $y$s are endogenous, you have a problem which cannot be solved by running a regression with ARMA errors nor an ARMAX model. Some (or all) of the regressors being endogenous is against the model assumptions and ruins the nice properties of coefficient estimators, so you cannot trust the coefficient estimates nor their standard errors. In such a setting, (structural) vector autoregressions ((S)VARs) are used. If you are *not* interested in $\gamma$s, you may build a VAR model and look into its impulse response functions (IRFs) and forecast error variance decomposition (FEVD) to see how the different variables interact. However, if you are interested in $\gamma$s, you would need a SVAR model, which is a little more involved.

* For example, you want to test some hypotheses based directly on $\beta$s.

Comment: Thank you for your very elaborate answer.

I will seriously explore the VAR method, but for the moment I have to continue using OLS models.

Should I conclude from what you wrote about the second equation that I can't even use the lagged dependant variable as a regressor?

Comment: Lagged dependent variable may be fine. The endogeneity issue is much less severe then. For example, a regular vector autoregression including lagged dependent variables (by definition) may be estimated consistently (although with a small-sample bias) by OLS.

Comment: @BladeVsResiduals, I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?